# Yandex mobile services robot - is it really a mobile user agent?

Tags: mobile, user-agent, yandex, yandex-webmaster-tools

As you can tell, I want my website indexed properly in as many search engines as possible. I'm looking at Yandex and using its "Server Response Check" tool which is similar to "Fetch as google" tool in GWT and one option it shows me as a bot to use is "Mobile Services Robot". The user-agent listed is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexImageResizer/2.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)`

At first I'm thinking maybe its an image processing bot in disguise, but then I could be wrong. Should I treat this particular user-agent string as a real mobile device trying to access my site, or is their real mobile user-agent string different. or do they even have one?

I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/check-yandex-robots.xml) you get ALL user agents of Yandex bot (this is the Yandex own page, so you shouldn't worry about whether this information's true).

Specially about your question's subject: **yes**, this is a mobile bot. Beside of it, there is another one mobile bot by Yandex. Its user agent is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)`